# WPF. TwoState element

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, controls

I'm implementing two state element. I have two xaml's (for first state and second state). I should change state at mouse click.

I create own Control child and use xaml

```
 <Style TargetType="l:ActionButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="l:ActionButton">
                <ContentControl x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                    <ContentControl.Resources>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonDownTemplate">
                            <Canvas>.....</Canvas>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonUpTemplate">
                            <Canvas>.....<Canvas>            
                       </ControlTemplate>
                    </ContentControl.Resources>
              </ContentControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

At OnApplyTemplate I handle template changing

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var btn = GetTemplateChild("LayoutRoot") as ContentControl;
        if (btn != null)
        {
            btn.MouseLeftButtonDown += (o, e) =>
            {
                //sample change template
                var template = (ControlTemplate)btn.FindResource("buttonDownTemplate");
                this.Template = template;
            };

        }

    }
```

But when I run app with my control I get: "An item with the same key has already been added." exception?

What's wrong. Is my way right?

Thanks, Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely not the way to go.  If you want a control that has two separate states, you should just restyle the `ToggleButton`.  You don't want completely swap out the ControlTemplate, as this is really slow.  Instead, you would put both of the visuals in the same template and show / hide them based on the state.

This is what a style for a ToggleButton would look like that accomplishes what you're after (and it requires no code behind):

```
<Style x:Key="twoStateButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Canvas x:Name="buttonDownTemplate" Background="#202020" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        ...
                    </Canvas>
                    <Canvas x:Name="buttonUpTemplate" Background="#C0C0C0">
                        ...
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonDownTemplate" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonUpTemplate" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```